# TSLint - Require Spaces Inside Array Brackets

Tags: typescript, tslint, jscs

Is it possible to enforce spaces inside array brackets, functions, if, for, switch, and object literals in TSLint just like we can do with [JSCS](http://jscs.info/rule/requireSpacesInsideArrayBrackets)?

For example:

```
const list = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

console.debug( list[ 1 ]; );

function foo ( a, b, c ) {
    ...
}

const obj = { bar: 'bar' };

while ( true ) {
    if ( false ) { 
        console.log( 'bar' );
    }
}
```